# What's the relationship between time complexity and complement?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complement

What's the relationship between time complexity and complement?

I do not understand what complement means to be used.

I do not understand the sentence below.

> Approach #2 (Two-pass Hash Table) [Accepted]
>
> To improve our run time complexity, we need a more efficient way to check if the complement exists in the array. If the complement exists, we need to look up its index. What is the best way to maintain a mapping of each element in the array to its index? A hash table.

https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/solution/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Complement` refers to the other number that when added to the current number will give you the value of the `target`.

If (for all) `a` + `b` = `target`, then `a`'s complement is `b`.

In order to see if a complement of ***a number*** is there, instead of looping through the array (which is O(n)), they are storing it (the elements in the source array) is a hash map.